# TT-Connect CT2-4650 CI doesn't initialize (Timeout?)

Tags: timeout, kali-linux, dmesg, dvb

I've tried to get a Techno Trend TT-connect CT2-4650 CI running under a Kali Linux, where I suppose the kernel is about the same as on a current Debian.

The compilation ran just fine.

The kernel module got loaded with no problems, but when I connect the device to my virtualbox I get the following messages in dmesg:

```
[  223.081774] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b48, idProduct=3012
[  223.081780] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  223.081785] usb 1-1: Product: TechnoTrend USB2.0
[  223.081789] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: CityCom GmbH
[  223.081792] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20130422
[  223.335895] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media stack.
[  223.335895]  As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't offer
[  223.335895]  enough quality for its usage in production.
[  223.335895]  Use it with care.
[  223.335895] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to linux-media@vger.kernel.org):
[  223.335895]  a32f7d1ad3744914273c6907204c2ab3b5d496a0 Merge branch 'v4l_for_linus' into staging/for_v3.9
[  223.335895]  6b9e50c463efc5c361496ae6a895cc966ff8025b [media] stv090x: On STV0903 do not set registers of the second path
[  223.335895]  f67102c49a123b32a4469b28407feb52b37144f5 [media] mb86a20s: remove global BER/PER counters if per-layer counters vanish
[  223.354451] WARNING: You are using an experimental version of the media stack.
[  223.354451]  As the driver is backported to an older kernel, it doesn't offer
[  223.354451]  enough quality for its usage in production.
[  223.354451]  Use it with care.
[  223.354451] Latest git patches (needed if you report a bug to linux-media@vger.kernel.org):
[  223.354451]  a32f7d1ad3744914273c6907204c2ab3b5d496a0 Merge branch 'v4l_for_linus' into staging/for_v3.9
[  223.354451]  6b9e50c463efc5c361496ae6a895cc966ff8025b [media] stv090x: On STV0903 do not set registers of the second path
[  223.354451]  f67102c49a123b32a4469b28407feb52b37144f5 [media] mb86a20s: remove global BER/PER counters if per-layer counters vanish
[  223.395840] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_ttv2
[  223.396104] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'TT-connect CT2-4650 CI' in warm state
[  223.396137] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[  223.396158] DVB: registering new adapter (TT-connect CT2-4650 CI)
[  223.428521] tt_usb MAC address=bc:ea:2b:65:02:d4
[  223.428529] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: MAC address: bc:ea:2b:65:02:d4
[  223.430036] tt_usb: tt_4650_attach, build on Jan 14 2014 09:46:32()
[  223.653935] usb 1-1: DVB: registering adapter 0 frontend 0 (Sit2 DVB-T2/C)...
[  225.716341] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 2nd usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[  227.836363] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 2nd usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[  227.892198] tt_usb: tt_ci_init()
[  229.908294] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 2nd usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[  229.908318] tt_usb: tt_ci_write_i2c: error, Reg=[0x00], Status=-110
[  231.908252] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[  231.908260] tt_usb: tt_ci_write_i2c: error, Reg=[0x1f], Status=-110
[  233.908325] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[  233.908332] tt_usb: tt_ci_write_i2c: error, Reg=[0x18], Status=-110
[  233.908337] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'TT-connect CT2-4650 CI' error while loading driver (-1)
[  233.909530] usb 1-1: dvb_usb_v2: 'TT-connect CT2-4650 CI' successfully deinitialized and disconnected
```

110 seems to be a Timeout issue, I can't quite see why though.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the shell script in the `media_build-tt` folder?

Best is to remove your `media_build-tt` folder, extract the archive again and run the following steps:

1. Change into the `media_build-tt` folder and run **one** of the following shell scripts:

   ```
   ./v4l/build_x64.sh       # 64 Bit kernel without DVB-C support<br />
   ./v4l/build_dvbc_x64.sh  # 64 Bit kernel with DVB-C support

   ./v4l/build_x86.sh       # 32 Bit kernel without DVB-C support<br />
   ./v4l/build_dvbc_x86.sh  # 32 Bit kernel with DVB-C support
   ```
2. Then run `make` and `make install` (the later as root or per `sudo`).

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux testing and the adapter (haven't tested the CI slot) is working from kernel 3.11 to 3.12 - but has some problems waking up from sleep unfortunately.